# How to determine the cause of young gc of a Java application

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently I found it had a frequent young gc in my java app. Since I had a 1600M young generation, and it did young gc every 10 seconds, I think there are too many unnecessary Objects that cause these gcs.

I know I can use jmap to do a heapdump to find out what cause full gc. But how can I find out what's in the young gen (cause a heapdump should clean the young gen and the young gen is varying all the time)

And another question : Will jstat -gcutil increase the gc frequency?

Comment: In general, it is normal to see frequent young gc. Because young GC is fast, it is hardly to be the root cause of performance problems. 

Suggest you can enable GC logging, ex:
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Xloggc:<file name>
And use GC analyze tool, like:http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html, to check time used by GC. Then you will see if the young GC is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** - [SJK's hh command](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/sjk-core/COMMANDS.md#hh-command)
It is using jmap underhood. If you run it with --dead-young it will do following.

- Perform Full GC
- Wait 10 seconds (fresh garbage produced)
- Take heap histogram without GC
- Immediately take perform GC and take histogram (like jmap --live)
- Compare two histogram and return difference - objects created in last 10 second and being collected.

**Option 2** - [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html)
It is a part of Java 8 JDK. It can sample object allocation on TLAB allocation failures. While not exactly accurate it is very good for detecting garbage spots in practice.

`jstat -gc` does not perform GC, it is using information via memory mapped file. JVM dump some metric to that file and `jstat` polls it.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I've tried sjk's hh. It printed sth like jmap -histo. java.lang.Integer / java.lang.String. I actually found sth about the cause, but it's not deep enough. I want to keep tracking these objects to find out who created them. But I don't find any option about heap dump in hh. What can I do to find out the initiator?

Comment: Also I found there are too many StackElementTrace, which means there are many Exceptions occur. But I don't find any log in my log file, so any chance to find who create these exceptions ?

Comment: @Alexis As I said sjk is just fancy wrapper of jmap. Try Java Mission Control, it can track object creation hot spots.

Comment: You can take heap dump containing garbage using jmap, and dig into heap dump to investigate these StackTraceElement instances. It may be some fancy framework using StackTraceElements to analyze caller stack or something like this.